# Как вместо кода сайта получить содержимое, используя requests?

Tags: python, requests

Я написал программу, но вместо списка абитуриентов я получаю код страницы HTML.

А как написать такую программу, чтобы она мне вернула список абитуриентов с сайте в виде текста ?

```
import requests

def read_website_data(url):
    try:
        # Отправляем GET-запрос к указанному URL
        response = requests.get(url)
        
        # Проверяем статус ответа
        if response.status_code == 200:
            # Если успешный ответ (код 200), выводим содержимое
            print("Данные с сайта:")
            print(response.text)
        else:
            # В случае неуспешного ответа выводим сообщение об ошибке
            print(f"Ошибка при получении данных. Код статуса: {response.status_code}")
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        # В случае ошибки запроса выводим сообщение об исключении
        print(f"Ошибка запроса: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Укажите URL сайта, который вы хотите прочитать
    target_url = "https://pk.mpei.ru/inform/list581bacc.html"
    
    # Вызываем функцию для чтения данных с сайта
    read_website_data(target_url)
```

Comment: тут нужна библиотека для парсинга beautifulsoup4

Comment: AleksandrFetisov спасибо ! Это то что и было мне необходимо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как и сказал @AleksandrFetisov я использовал `beautifulsoup4` и всё заработало.

Спасибо !

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def read_website_data(url):
    try:
        # Отправляем GET-запрос к указанному URL
        response = requests.get(url)
        
        # Проверяем статус ответа
        if response.status_code == 200:
            # Если успешный ответ (код 200), парсим HTML с помощью BeautifulSoup
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
            # Выводим содержимое сайта
            print("Данные с сайта:")
            print(soup.prettify())  # Выводим отформатированный HTML
        else:
            # В случае неуспешного ответа выводим сообщение об ошибке
            print(f"Ошибка при получении данных. Код статуса: {response.status_code}")
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        # В случае ошибки запроса выводим сообщение об исключении
        print(f"Ошибка запроса: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Укажите URL сайта, который вы хотите прочитать
    target_url = "https://pk.mpei.ru/inform/list581bacc.html"
    
    # Вызываем функцию для чтения данных с сайта
    read_website_data(target_url)
```